# Problem with Firefox gradient color when hardware acceleration enabled - RTX A500

Tags: firefox, browser, gradient

I have a weird problem with gradients and firefox, where the gradient seems to have a grey overlay. This only happens when hardware acceleration is turned on.

It shows up even on th the official mozilla dev wiki. To show what i mean, here is a screenshot from chrome and firefox. Both are the image from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createConicGradient

[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sK9Af.png)
[Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJ7Ki.png)

The same problem can be seen here: https://canvasdraw.limboy.me/

[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGjZZ.png)
[Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiFD0.png)

Is this a local problem? I am new to web dev and no idea how hardware acceleration influences colors.

My GPU is the RTX A500, all drivers updated.

Does anyone know what causes this and how to fix it?

Comment: please see why you should not upload images: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a Firefox internal bug.
For those who are interested: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1851963